# How to check if element has been hidden by .hide(); - jQuery 3.6

Tags: jquery

I have without luck tried to make a check if an element has been hidden with `$('Reaction' + val).hide();`, but any attempt (with below testet code) has been less than usefull, and have not given the result I need.

I have tried different variation of check:

`if ($('#Reaction' + val).is(':hidden')) {`

`if ( $('#Reaction' + val).css('display') == 'none' || $(element).css("visibility") == "hidden"){`

`var isHidden = $('#Reaction' + val).is(':hidden');`

.. and a few more

**What I am doing with the script:**

In the ***// Hide Emoji*** part, I am removig an emoji by `$('#Reaction' + val).hide();` and in the ***// Change/Add Emoji*** I need to check if the emoji have been hidden and run different code depending on hidden/shown.

What can I do to make this check work?

**My jQuery:**

```js
// Change/Add Emoji

$(document).unbind().on('click', '.messageemoji', function() {

  var val = $(this).closest("table").attr("data-val")
  var emoji = $(this).data("emoji")

  if ($('#Reaction' + val).is(':hidden')) {
    alert('Yes, Element is Hidden');
  } else {
    alert('No, Element is not Hidden');
  }


  $('#Reaction' + val).show();

  changeemojioutsound.play();
  changeemojioutsound.currentTime = 0;

  $('#Reaction' + val).find("img").addClass("animate__animated animate__zoomOutDown");

  setTimeout(function() {
    changeemojiinsound.play();
    changeemojiinsound.currentTime = 0;
    $('#Reaction' + val).find("img").removeClass("animate__animated animate__zoomOutDown");
    $('#Reaction' + val).find("img").attr("src", 'img/smileyani/' + emoji);
    $('#Reaction' + val).find("img").addClass("animate__animated animate__zoomInUp");
  }, 500)

  setTimeout(function() {
    $('#Reaction' + val).find("img").removeClass("animate__animated animate__zoomInUp");
  }, 1500)

});

// Hide Emoji

$(document).on('click', '.removeemojibtn', function() {

  var val = $(this).attr('data-val');

  console.log(val)

  removeemojioutsound.play();
  removeemojioutsound.currentTime = 0;

  $('#Reaction' + val).find("img").addClass("animate__animated animate__zoomOutRight");

  setTimeout(function() {
    $('#Reaction' + val).find("img").removeClass("animate__animated animate__zoomOutRight animate__zoomOutDown animate__zoomInUp");
    $('#Reaction' + val).hide();
  }, 1500)

});
```

Comment: You're defining 'val' AFTER you've used the variable to check if the element is hidden. So it's probably not looking for the right element in your IF statement.

Comment: @Phaelaxz .. you are right, that was a thing I forgot to change before posting, I have now corrected it in the snippet .. having the check after does no difference, it still says that it is not hidden even if it should be, so that is not it.

Answer (score 0):

OK, all other checks does not work for some reason, but I found out that if I did a check using true/false method it will detect if it is hidden or not .. the working script is :

```
var currentEmoji = "#Reaction" + val;
if ( $(currentEmoji).is(":hidden") == true ){
      console.log('it is hidden')
  } else {
    console.log('it is shown')
}
```